# angular protractor how to test click with a redirect state

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Be patient I'm new at protractor.

I've got this code:

```
angular.module('my.users')
    .controller('SessionSigninController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Users', '$state',
        function($scope, $rootScope, Users, $state) {
            $scope.user = {};
            $scope.errors = [];
            $scope.save = function() {
                Users.signin($scope.user).then(
                    function(data) { 
                        if(data.success){
                            $rootScope.$emit('loggedin',data.user);
                            return $state.go('home');
                        }
                        $scope.errors = data.errors;
                    }
                );
            };
        }
    ])
```

I'm testing it like (green bar):

```
describe('users :', function() {
    describe('register', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            browser.get('/#!/user/register');
        });
        it('btn should be disabled', function() {
            var btn = element(by.css('button.btn-primary'));
            expect(browser.isElementPresent(btn)).toBe(true);
            expect(btn.isEnabled()).toBe(false);
        });
        it('btn should be enabled', function() {
            var btn = element(by.css('button.btn-primary'));
            element(by.model('user.fullname')).sendKeys('test user');
            element(by.model('user.email')).sendKeys('test@etest.io');
            element(by.model('user.username')).sendKeys('testusere');
            element(by.model('user.password')).sendKeys('testsecret');
            element(by.model('user.password_confirmation')).sendKeys('testsecret');
            expect(browser.isElementPresent(btn)).toBe(true);
            expect(btn.isEnabled()).toBe(true);
            btn.click();
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/\/#!/);

        });
    });

});
```

1. Is it the right way to test the 'redirect' to home ?
2. Why even if the form is invalid (email unique) the test is green ?
3. Is there a way to mock the test ?

**END UP** (see reply)

```
describe('users :', function() {
    describe('register', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            browser.get('/#!/user/register');
        });
        it('btn should be disabled', function() {
            var btn = element(by.css('button.btn-primary'));
            expect(browser.isElementPresent(btn)).toBe(true);
            expect(btn.isEnabled()).toBe(false);
        });
        it('btn should be enabled', function() {
            var random = ~~(Math.random() * 1000);
            var btn = element(by.css('button.btn-primary'));
            element(by.model('user.fullname')).sendKeys('test user');
            element(by.model('user.email')).sendKeys('test'+random+'@test.io');
            element(by.model('user.username')).sendKeys('testuser'+random);
            element(by.model('user.password')).sendKeys('testsecret');
            element(by.model('user.password_confirmation')).sendKeys('testsecret');
            expect(browser.isElementPresent(btn)).toBe(true);
            expect(btn.isEnabled()).toBe(true);
            btn.click();
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/\/#!\/$/);
            var userMenu = element.all(by.css('ul.dropdown-menu li'));
            expect(userMenu.count()).toBe(3);
         });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your test looks good. It is easy to read. I would suggest adding an extra expect to make sure that you actually were able to log in. Check for the title or for a "logout" link or whatever is visible after logging in.

Your test passes because the regular expression in

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/\/#!/);
```

Matches `'/#!/user/register'`. Try adding a dollar sign at the end:

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(\/#!/$);
```